# How does this function get the id of the most recent post?

Tags: functions

Here's a function that does what I need it to do. Someone else wrote it. I want to understand how it is doing it. (More will be added to it FYI.)

The goal here was to get the id of the most recent post. I understand what the WordPress function part is doing. I don't understand what is happening to set the value for `$thePostID` after the WordPress  function has found the first post. In particular, the [0] and [ID].

Can someone please explain?

```
function prepare_payment() {
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );
  $thePostID = $recent_posts[0]['ID'];
  echo $thePostID;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prepare_payment()` is calling [`wp_get_recent_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) which returns an array of post by default. Only one post is being returned in this case, due to the `$numberposts` parameter being set to `1`.

`$recent_posts` holds the array of posts returned by `wp_get_recent_posts()`. The following line is setting `$thePostID` to the ID of the first post in the `$recent_posts` array ([arrays are zero indexed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)):

```
$thePostID = $recent_posts[0]['ID'];
```

Finally, the ID is echo'd using the line `echo $thePostID;`

Edit: Here is an example of the array returned by `wp_get_recent_posts()`, which itself is a wrapper for [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 418
            [post_author] => 2
            [post_date] => 2025-01-01 00:00:00
            [post_date_gmt] => 2025-01-01 00:00:00
            [post_content] => This post is scheduled to be published in the future.

It should not be displayed by the theme.
            [post_title] => Scheduled
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => future
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => scheduled
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2016-04-11 04:28:22
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-04-11 04:28:22
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/?p=418
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => post
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

You can replicate this by adding a simple debugging statement to `prepare_payment()`:

```
function prepare_payment() {
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );

    // Temporary debugging statement
    print_r( $recent_posts );

  $thePostID = $recent_posts[0]['ID'];
  echo $thePostID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, James. I added an example array to the answer.

Comment: THAT is exactly what I needed to know! Tips like that are the true education in learning to code. Reading the Codex only goes so far in giving one an understanding. Seeing the values returned makes it all very clear. Many, many thanks Dave!

Comment: Very happy to help, James! Happy coding!